# Dagger 2 throws error for Component.Builder : @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components:

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have a component `AppComponent`

```
@Component
public interface AppComponent {

}
```

I have added a Component builder to this, to take external dependencies.

```
@Component
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder setContext(Context context);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Now, I can build this component in the application class

```
    AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                                        .setContext(this)
                                        .build();
```

Everything works perfect.

Now I have another Component, say `OtherComponet`

```
@Component
public interface OtherComponent {
}
```

And I want to add this component as a dependency for `AppComponent`

```
@Component(dependencies = {OtherComponent.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder setContext(Context context);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Now, If I compile, I get the error

```
error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [dagger.OtherComponent]
    interface Builder {
```

Make sense. Because I have overridden the default Builder for AppComponent and my custom Component.Builder doesn't have a setter to set the `OtherComponent` instance.

So, I add this method to my Custom.Builder

```
@Component(dependencies = {OtherComponent.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder setContext(Context context);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder setOtherComponent(OtherComponent otherComponent);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Now if I compile, I get the exact same error

```
error: @Component.Builder is missing setters for required modules or components: [dagger.OtherComponent]
```

What's wrong here? I've already given the setter `setOtherComponent` with `@BindsInstance` but still why is it saying `missing setters for required modules or component`

NOTE: if I didn't go for a Custom Component.Builder then dagger will generate builder method for the dependent component

Eg:

```
@Component(dependencies = {OtherComponent.class})
public interface AppComponent {
}
```

This would create a builder which can be used like

```
 AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                            .otherComponent(otherComponentInstance)
                            .build();
```

Comment: Did you try remove bindInstance when add setOtherComponenet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put `@BindsInstance` while creating dependent component, it can bind only exposed method inside `OtherComponent`

```
@Component(dependencies = {OtherComponent.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder setContext(Context context);

        Builder setOtherComponent(OtherComponent otherComponent);

        AppComponent build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing `Builder setOtherComponent(OtherComponent otherComponent);` Thanks!